# How is this algebraic step justified. (Inequalities)

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I don't understand why this is allowed or the logic behind it:

$P[X^2 - 2X < 8] = P[x^2 -2X + 1 < 9] = p[ (X - 1)^2 < 9 ] $

$P[-3 < (X - 1) < 3]$ (this step right here). What is the logic behind this step? what is the logic behind introducing a 2nd inequality?

Answer (score 2):

If $(X - 1)^2 < 9$, we can take the square root of both sides. As we are dealing with an inequality, we need to use the fact that the square root function is increasing, that is, if $x_1 < x_2$, then $\sqrt{x_1} < \sqrt{x_2}$. Therefore we have $\sqrt{(X-1)^2} < 3$. As $\sqrt{(X-1)^2} = |X - 1|$, we have $|X - 1| < 3$ and therefore $-3 < X - 1 < 3$.

Comment: okay, so for clarification, if I did: $$-5< (x-1)<3$$ it woulda been equivalent thing? Or does it have to be -3?

Comment: It's not equivalent. That allows $X - 1 = -4$ for example, but $|X - 1| = |-4| = 4$ which is not less than $3$.

Answer (score 1):

They use a technique called [Completing the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square). In this case we have taken the equation $X^2-2X<8$, and noted that it is equivalent to $X^2-2X+1<8+1=9$. Now we can rewrite the inequality as $(X-1)^2<9$ which is only true if $|X-1|<3$. It's from this that we get the final form: $-3<X-1<3$.